# JWT, Stateless Authentication, and Security

Tags: security, authentication, jwt

I am working on an application where scalability is a big concern. In the past I've used session-based authentication, but decided to go with a stateless server this time around in order to facilitate horizontal scaling.

I am not security expert, but in researching JWTs, it began to seem like these are very insecure. The whole reason we hash passwords is so that if our database is compromised, the attacker cannot impersonate a user. With JWT, we store a secret on the server. If the attacker gains access to the secret, can't they impersonate any user they want? Doesn't this mean that using JWTs would have the same level of security as storing plain text passwords?

I have read that people will sometimes use reddis to cross reference JWTs, but then the server isn't stateless, and I fail to see the benefit of using JWTs at all.

Could someone help clarify this issue for me?

Answer (score 4):

Session based authentication systems, at least any that are worth using, also store a secret on the server. Just like the JWT, the secret is used to sign the data stored in the cookie that session based authentication uses. So this is no different than a JWT.

All of this is totally unrelated to password storage, as the password is only used when you don't have a cookie/JWT.

EDIT:

Not sure what to say about using Redis in conjunction with a JWT... What is being stored in Redis, the token? That seems pointless, as all the server needs to know is the secret to decode the token.

Here are some of the benefits to a using a JWT:

- It's stateless, as you've already mentioned
- It's not subject to CSRF/XSRF attacks. These attacks work by tricking your browser into sending the cookie to a server that didn't generate the cookie. This can't happen w/a JWT b/c the browser doesn't send the JWT automatically like it does w/cookies.
- JWT's are [standardized](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519). There is a well defined way to generate them, which means that JWT's are more portable and the process has been vetted by the security community.

Comment: The server does not need to know a secret to decode the token. Tokens are base64 encoded and therefore can be easily decoded by anyone. The server only needs the public key to validate the signature.

Comment: @MvdD this is interesting ... I noticed this in a [node JWT](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) package that you could decode the token by passing their API the secret or a public key. But everything I read (and other apis I've used) don't seem to talk about the public key. On further review, it looks like you need to know the secret when using HMAC, but can use public key if you sign with RSA or ECDSA (from the above node package's docs).

Comment: Not all session based authentication systems work the same way. Some store a random value that is checked server-side on every request. This allows tokens to be revoked easily on the server. Also note that only JWTs that are stored in browser storage offer protection against CSRF, any that are stored in cookies are just as vulnerable.

Answer (score 2):

The server consuming a JWT token (resource server) **does not need access to any secret**. All it needs is the *public key* that belongs to the private key with which the token is digitally signed.

The authorization server that issues the token needs to keep its signing key secret obviously. But the nice thing about token based authentication is that this server can be created by an external party with much more resources/expertise to keep these things secret (Google, Facebook, Microsoft etc).

The resource server does not need to check the database to validate the token as you would need in case of username and password. This helps the scalability of the system and takes away a single point of failure.

If a client/user loses the JWT token, an attacker can impersonate the client/user until the token expires. A good reason to keep the lifetime of tokens short.

I don't see the point of storing JWT tokens in in a Reddis cache. There's no need to share tokens between servers as each call comes with a token in the `Authorization` HTTP header. Storing them in a cache only increases the risk of tokens being stolen.