# add security to stateless JWT authentication

Tags: php, security, jwt, backend

I've implemented an stateless server which im using JWT for let users access the APIs. my concern here is about security. same question before but with not well answered:
 [JWT, Stateless Authentication, and Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238642/jwt-stateless-authentication-and-security)

Question: using some factors like JWE(to encrypt the token) or using a strong secret to sign the tokens &... can make the procedure more secure but what if the ALL SECURITY WE IMPLEMENTED JUST DEPENDS ON SECRET KEY

what if the SECRET KEY gets stolen?
then no matter how many security layers we used, the hacker can make a valid token using the secret key and access all APIs. is there any solution to make it more secure?

Answer (score 1):

If your secret key to generate your token is compromised, juste change it. That will invalidate all previous created JWT token.

Comment: how i must be aware that my key was stolen? it can get compromised again the same way it was before :)

Comment: If the system where your application is hosted is so compromising, JWT tokens are probably not the first of your worries :)

Comment: but that is not my answer btw :)

Comment: But what answer do you expect? Even in the most secure place, if you lose the key regularly, you have no choice but to change the locks ^^

Comment: As an example, [Google](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs) use several keys. Which one is actually used to sign the tokens? You don't know and you don't care. What is important is to change a key when you know it is compromised or after a period of time (e.g. 2 weeks).